# MYSQL next month query not working

Tags: mysql

I hope someone can help me with my query. I am trying to get all the rows from a mysql database where 'end' falls inside next calendar month. At the moment my query is only pulling rows where 'start' is inside the next calendar month.

```
   if (! empty($_GET['skill'])) $whereClauses[] ="skill LIKE('%".mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$_GET['skill'])."%')";
if (!empty($_GET['start']))
    if ($_GET['start'] == "today") {
        $whereClauses[] = "START = CURDATE()";
    }
else if ($_GET['start'] == "tomorrow") {
        $whereClauses[] = "START = DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL( 9 - IF( DAYOFWEEK( CURDATE( ) ) =1, 8, DAYOFWEEK( CURDATE( ) ) ) ) DAY )";   
    }
else if ($_GET['start'] == "next_week") {
        $whereClauses[] = "START = DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL( 9 - IF( DAYOFWEEK( CURDATE( ) ) =1, 8, DAYOFWEEK( CURDATE( ) ) ) ) 
DAY )";   
    }
else if ($_GET['start'] == "this_month") {
        $whereClauses[] = "START BETWEEN DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL( DAY( CURDATE( ) ) -1 ) DAY ) AND LAST_DAY( NOW( ) )";   
    }
    else if ($_GET['start'] == "next_month") {
        $whereClauses[] = "start BETWEEN DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)),INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)))-1 DAY) AND LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))";
    }
else if ($_GET['start'] == "in_future") {
        $whereClauses[] = "START > CURDATE()";   
    }
```

and then

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM mytable " .$where."";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was this

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE  
FLOOR(start/100)<=FLOOR(NOW()/100000000)+1 AND
FLOOR(  end/100)>=FLOOR(NOW()/100000000)+1
```

Courtesy of Cars10 on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423747/return-rows-for-next-month-mysql/32423949?noredirect=1#comment52743089_32423949)