# Return rows for next month, MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table which stores users' availability, stored in 'start' and 'end' columns as date fields.

I have a form where other users can search through the 'availabilty' with various periods like, today, tomorrow and next week . I'm trying to figure out how to construct the query to get all the rows for users who are available 'next month'.

The 'start' values maybe from today and the 'end' value might might be three  months away but if next month falls between 'start' and 'end' then I would want that row returned.
The nearest I can get is with the query below but that just returns rows where 'start' falls within next month. Many thanks,

```
sql= "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE start BETWEEN DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)),INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)))-1 DAY) AND LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are interested in anything that happens in the full month following the current date you could try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE
FLOOR(start/100000000)<=FLOOR(NOW()/100000000)+1 AND
FLOOR(  end/100000000)>=FLOOR(NOW()/100000000)+1
```

This query make use of the fact that `datetime` values are stored in MySql internally as a number like

```
SELECT now()+0
--> 20150906130640
```

where the digits `09` refer to the current month. `FLOOR(NOW()/100000000)` filters out the first digits of the number (in this case:`201509`).  The `WHERE` conditions now simply test whether the `start` date is anywhere *before the end* of the next month and the `end` date is at least *in or after the period* of the next month.

(In my version I purposely left out the condition that `start` needs to be "after today", since a period that has started earlier seems in my eyes still applicable for your described purpose. If, however, you wanted that condition included too you could simply add an `AND start > now()` at the end of your `WHERE` clause.)

**Edit**

As your SQLfiddle is set-up with a `date` instead of a (as I was assuming) `datetime` column your dates will be represented differently in mumeric format like `20150907` and a simple division by 100 will now get you the desired month-number for comparison (`201509`):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE  
FLOOR(start/100)<=FLOOR(NOW()/100000000)+1 AND
FLOOR(  end/100)>=FLOOR(NOW()/100000000)+1
```

The number returned by `NOW()` is still a 14-digit figure and needs to be divided by `100000000`. See your updated fiddle here: [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e0f7/5)

I also added another record ('Charlie') which does not fulfill your requirements.

**Update**

To better accommodate change-of-year scenarios I updated my [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e0f7/33). The `where` clause is now based on `12*YEAR(..)+MONTH(..)` type functions.

Comment: Much appreciated however I'm having trouble making this work. I've made this sqlfiddle, perhaps you can explain why the query returns zero results. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/811626/3

Comment: I updated my answer. Tip: when uncertain about the results try a `select start+0`. This will output the start-date in the numerical format that is then manipulated by my division and floor operations.

Comment: It works perfectly and wonderfully explained. Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm wondering how using the same fiddle as above I can find results that fall within next week?

Comment: You could use a modified version like this one [Weeks-SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd3b7/6) by applying the functions `100*YEAR(...)+MONTH(...)`.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks very much, now I've got to get my head around how exactly that works.

Comment: Unfortunately, my solution will not get you correct results when a change of year is involved. Using `52*YEAR(...)+WEEK()` will be slightly better, but in some years there are more than 52 weeks per year...

Comment: Using the floor() method I'm trying to return rows where the dates fall on tomorrow. I thought this would be easy...I've been trying this SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE -- filtered results
FLOOR(start/1000000)<=FLOOR(NOW()/100000000) AND
FLOOR(  end/1000000)>=FLOOR(NOW()/100000000)+1 on this fiddle but no luck [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e0f7/5)

Comment: Try [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e0f7/46) to solve your problem. 'Tomorrow' in Mysql is: `now() + interval 1 day`.

Comment: Or, to *just* make sure that 'tomorrow' sits between `start` and `end` do: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY BETWEEN start AND end`, ([see here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e0f7/51)).